# React app rewired , Installing module federation with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend

I am using below code to install module federation plugin on top of react app rewired :

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = 
require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

module.exports = {
    webpack: function(config, env) {
        config.externals = function(context, request, callback) {
            if (/canvg|pdfmake/.test(request)) {
                return callback(null, "commonjs " + request);
            }
            callback();
        };
        config.plugins.push(new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "app_1",
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            remotes: {
                app_2: "app_2@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js",
            },
        }));
        return config;
    },
};
```

Here is my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "Sample_app",
  "version": "0.1.358",
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.20",
    "@deck.gl/mesh-layers": "^8.6.8",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.1.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.1.1",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.1.0",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.1.1",
    "@reactour/tour": "^2.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@wsp/map-gl": "^2.1.11",
    "@wsp/map-react": "^1.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "md5-file": "^5.0.0",
    "mui-datatables": "^4.0.0",
    "node": "^16.13.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-data-export": "^0.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^5.4.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:local": "react-app-rewired start",
    "start": "REACT_APP_ENV_HOST=$REACT_APP_ENV_HOST node --max-http-header-size 16384 build/server",
    "build": "REACT_APP_ENV_HOST=$REACT_APP_ENV_HOST react-app-rewired build && cp -R ./server/* ./build && npm run moveFiles",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "moveFiles": "cd build && mkdir channelperformance && cp -r ./static ./channelperformance/static",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
    "test:update": "react-scripts test -u"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!/node_modules/",
      "!src/coverage/**",
      "!src/index.js",
      "!src/stories/**"
    ],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/src/constants",
      "/src/routes",
      "/src/helper",
      "/src/reportWebVitals.js",
      "/src/components/Drilldown/DownloadMuiTable",
      "/src/components/Drilldown/ReactVirtualized",
      "/src/components/Drilldown/Common/ChannelBreakdown.js"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!(@amcharts)\\/).+\\.js$"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@e2e-test-utils/ui-shield": "^3.0.3",
    "@e2e-test-utils/ui-shield-utilities": "^4.1.5-0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack4": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack4": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.2.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.6",
    "babel-jest-amcharts": "^0.0.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.4",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "prettier": "2.3.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9"
  }
}
```

However it throws an error saying "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')". I think it's having a conflict with some library .

Please help. if any integration examples with MF plugin, please provide those links.

Comment: Does your code need to be a single line? You might want to consider people who might want to read it...

Comment: Fixed the formatting sir!